# how to set div width relative to content on ignoring parent's width

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am looking for a way to set div width based on the enclosed content instead of inheriting the parent's width, for exemple :

```
<div id="parent" style="width:100px">
     <div id="child"> <!-- i want to add css to this div -->

         <p style="width:200px;"> this s atext</p>
        <img src="this s an image" style="width:300px;">


     </div>  
</div>
```

I want is to make width of `#child` 500px automatically, I don't want to set the width of `#child` manually , because in my real case I don't know the width of it content, (check comment below for more details about my case)

Note that all of the following solutions didn't work with me:

```
display:inline;
width:auto;
overflow:visible;
```

Can you help me please?

Comment: Can you further explain why you want the child div to be much wider than its parent div?

Comment: i m working on a zk  project and i m trying to add a new bar using "marquee" element , but it seems that div where i put all the news doesnt take the width of it content but take parent's width and force all elements inside to break line , and i dont want this to happen

Comment: and when i change "news" div to 10000px for example , it does work perfectly , but i m not allowed to do so because i dont always know the width of elements inside that div .

Comment: Please see my answer below.

Comment: "i m trying to add a new bar using "marquee" element" - Well the good news you're not supposed to use the `marquee` element because it's been deprecated under HTML5.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is one way that could work for your layout.

If the **HTML** looks like the following:

```
<div id="parent" style="width:100px">
    <div id="child"> <!-- i want to add css to this div -->
        <p style="width:200px;">this is text</p>
        <img src="http://placekitten.com/600/400" style="width:300px;">
    </div>
</div>
```

apply the following **CSS**:

```css
#parent {
    border: 1px dashed blue;
}
#child {
    background-color: beige;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
#child p {
    border: 1px dotted blue;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;
    margin: 0;
}
#child img {
    border: 1px dotted blue;
    vertical-align: top;
}
```

The borders are for illustration only to demonstrate how the edges of the various boxes.

It looks like you want the two child elements, `p` and `img` to be on a single line,
hence have a total width of 500px (200px + 300px).

First, apply `display: inline-block` to the `p` so that it can flow inline with the
image.

To keep the `p` and the `img` on a single line, you can apply `white-space: nowrap` to
the `#child` containing block.

Alternatively, you could make sure there is no white space (for example, a line feed) between the two elements, but this may not feasible if the content is coming from a
CMS or some other feed.

Note that the `#child` elements takes on the width of the `#parent` block, and the
descendant elements overflow accordingly.  This may not be ideal but it can be fixed
if so required.

You may need to set a maximum width to `#child` depending on your actual content.

See demo at: http://jsfiddle.net/audetwebdesign/c94Ya/

In Firefox, the result looks like:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to set the width 500px for child div. but it doesn't take the width because the parent container width is 100px.

If you want set 500px for child div means rechange the style for parent div 500px or above 500px that time only the child div will work.

for example

```
<div id="parent" style="width:100%">
     <div id="child" style="width:500px"> <!-- i want to add css to this div -->

         <p style="width:200px;"> this s atext</p>
        <img src="this s an image" style="width:300px;">


     </div>  
</div>
```

In this example i changed the parent css width 100px to 100%

Comment: i dont want to set the width of "child" manualy , because in my case i dont know the width of it content , check my new comment on the quetion to understant my case , thx :)

Answer (score 0):

try and make the ID separate by using `z-index` in your css.
it is used to put objects on top of each other while not effected by each others css

```
#child {
width: 500px;
z-index: 100;
}
```

from here any ID set with a `z-index` higher then 100 will be above the child ID.
and any ID set with a `z-index` lower then 100 will be beneath the child ID.

Comment: i dont want to set the width of "child" manualy , because in my case i dont know the width of it content , check my new comment on the quetion to understant my case , thx :)

Answer (score 0):

When I tried this, the red border was wider than the black border

```
<div id="parent" style="width:100px;border: 1px solid black">
     <div id="child" style="width:500px;border: 1px solid red"> <!-- i want to add css to this div -->
         <p style="width:200px;"> this s atext</p>
     </div>
</div>
```

Comment: i dont want to set the width of "child" manualy , because in my case i dont know the width of it content , check my new comment on the quetion to understant my case , thx :)

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are looking for?

**http://jsfiddle.net/A9xDG/**

```
<div id="parent" style="width:200px; background: red; height: 400px">
     <div id="child" style="background: yellow; width: 500px;">
        <p> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, </p>
         <img src="this s an image" style="width:100px" />
      </div> 
</div>
```

**Update: http://jsfiddle.net/A9xDG/3/**

Comment: u just set the width of "child":500px , in my real case i cant do this because i dont know the width of it content , got me ?  :D

Comment: In this case you cannot nest the divs and use absolute positioning instead. But I really don't understand why you want to achieve this. See my updated answer